# Applying changes made from git

Tags: git

I'm trying to change my workflow and started to use git instead of ftp. I chose Tower to manage my local repository. I created a bare git on my server and cloned it through Tower. So far so good. When I commit and push my changes, my files dont update (i opened them though FTP and they didnt change). So i deleted my local repo and cloned from the remote server, and the changes were there, the files were changed. Does anyone have any ideia why this is so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the differences between a working copy (that contains checked out files) and a repo (that contains commits and gets updated on push). If you want to update a working copy when a related repository receives new commits, you probably need to write a `post-receive` hook.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Is there a git command to apply those changes from the repo into my working copy manually? If theres any, should I run the command on my repo or working copy?

Comment: `git checkout master` or some more appropriate `git checkout` command will update the working copy to a specified state. You run the command in the working copy which you need to update (in your case it's apparently the workig copy on the server, attached to the repo to which you push your changes).

Comment: I ran a `git pull` and then a `git checkout` as you suggested and it worked fine. thanks a ton.

Comment: You don't need `git pull` if you already pushed to this repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using similar approach to deploy my homepage. Here's how my `post-receive` hook looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
export GIT_DIR=/path/to/bare-git-repo
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/working-tree
cd "$GIT_WORK_TREE"
git reset --hard
git checkout
```

Please note, I'm using **separate directories** for git bare repository itself and its working tree; in case you have working tree with `.git` subdirectory, this should be sufficient:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-receive 
#!/bin/sh -eu
git checkout -f
```

You also have to execute this command once on **receiving repository side**:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Otherwise git would not accept pushes to repo with checked out working tree.